# How to disable data inheritance of angular ui router states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I disable a child state in angular `UI-router` from inheriting its parent state's data?

For example, I have a parent and child state as follows:

```
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
      data:{
         customData1:  "Hello",
      }
   })
   .state('parent.child', {
      data:{

      }
   });
```

Here the child state(`parent.child`) inherits the data(`customData1`) of its parent. 
How can I disable it from inheriting parent's data?

Comment: I'd like to be able to disable this inheritance too. I keep data specific to each state and need always to remember to overwrite it in children. Not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure why would you like to do that.. you can hide the parent implementation:

#### [Inherited Custom Data](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-custom-data)

> Child states will inherit data properties from parent state(s), which they can overwrite.

```
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
      data:{
         customData1:  "Hello",
         customData2:  "World!"
      }
   })
   .state('parent.child', {
      data:{
         // customData1 inherited from 'parent'
         // but we'll overwrite customData2
         customData2:  "UI-Router!"
      }
   });

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState){ 
    var greeting = toState.data.customData1 + " " + toState.data.customData2;
    console.log(greeting);

    // Would print "Hello World!" when 'parent' is activated
    // Would print "Hello UI-Router!" when 'parent.child' is activated
})
```

Comment: Here, the parent.child state will inherit the customData1 from the parent. I don't want that to happen. I want the parent.child.data.customData1 to be null.(or undefined).In other words, I want to disable the data inheritance from parent to child state.

Comment: I can't do that. Thats why I mentioned I want to disable the inheritance of data :)

Comment: Stop inheritance of `data` is impossible. The above answer is the soltuion. *(But from my perspective, just my point of view - that could not be issue. You should be able to handle your state definitions. It is in your hands. If you need different setting in your child, then use data : { subChildSetting : {...}})*  Sorry for not having "the answer". Good luck with UI-Router anyhow

Comment: Thank you.It is also ok if I come to know whether the data is inherited or custom defined. I had posted another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170670/how-to-know-whether-angular-ui-router-custom-data-is-inherited-from-the-parent-s). Can you please let me know if that is possible?

Comment: ;) ;) ;) well it is so hard with you! do you know that? you already have the answer but you again say: I do not want it ;) Simply, your if (`if(parent.child.data.customData1==parent.data.customData1)`) statement is the way. You can create some Helper method, but evaluation will be exactly the same. Good luck sir ;)

Comment: :) but this test will fail if I explicitly mention the same value in parent as well as child state :) ie,`$stateProvider.state('parent', {
      data:{
         customData1:  "Hello";
      }
   })
   .state('parent.child', {
      data:{
         // customData1 inherited from 'parent'
         // but we'll overwrite customData2
         customData1:  "Hello";
      }
   });`