# Angular ui-router: How to load child controller instead of parent controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have the following nested routes in my Angular app:

```
.state('mapping', {
    url: '/mapping',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/mapping/mapping.html',
    controller: 'MapCtrl as map',
    abstract: true,
    authenticate: true
})
.state('mapping.all', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/mapping/partials/all.html',
    authenticate: true
})
.state('mapping.project', {
    url: '/:projectName',
    controller: 'ProjectCtrl as proj',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/mapping/partials/project.html',
    authenticate: true
})
```

When accessing `'mapping.project'`, `ProjectCtrl` never gets loaded. Instead, `MapCtrl` is loaded as if I was still on the parent state.

How can I override the parent controller with another controller that is specific to that child state?

I want this controller to get loaded every time I access that specific child state, which just won't happen if I have a single parent controller for every child state.

Comment: Can u share the final url? Does it contain a projectName?

Comment: Yes, it does contain a project name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any `controller` is related to `view` *(not to `state`)*. It means, that if:

> ...When accessing mapping.project, ProjectCtrl never gets loaded....

That view was not loaded. And it mostly means, that **parent** `view` *(`app/components/mapping/mapping.html`)* did not contain target:

```
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

So, if we will place into parent template a target *(`ui-view=""`)*, child state will inject its view into that place. But that will not replace the parent controller. It will

- call parent `ctrl` when parent (or child directly) is accessed
- if child is accessed from parent, parent `ctrl` won't be reinit, but child `ctrl` will be initiated

Check these for more details:

- [Angular UI Router - Nested States with multiple layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310)
- [Nested states or views for layout with leftbar in ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28800644/1679310)
- [How to disable data inheritance of angular ui router states](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27183310/1679310)

Comment: I do have a <div ui-view></div> within mapping.html. Should I replace it with 
<div ui-view=""></div>?

Comment: No, that won't be the issue ... I could show you that in a plunker.. sec please

Comment: I've seen this plunkr you created: http://plnkr.co/edit/qzI25MKsXBUvw2b45bef?p=preview This problem is very very similar to what I have. I also need a lot of nested views with a sidebar on my Angular application.

Comment: Exactly... that is the way to go

Comment: Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/1aQbOos1aoGhUIAg30r6?p=preview - it does what described above. If we go to mappings - substate `all` is selected as the default. If we pass the id, every time the `ProjectCtrl` is called, because its view is injected into parent `ui-view` (I added alert to that ctrl to show that feature... could be turned off ;)

Comment: I am very sorry but it turns out I still have the same problem, this is giving me a big headache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076944/angular-ui-router-child-state-controller-not-getting-called I tried to give more information here. I know that your plunkr is working, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I tried to find some quick solution... added answer. Let me know if I should remove it (to get other form some others)